# Как организовать передачу на сервер файла с именем «%^##76 / // \ ^^ [ ] : .jpg»?

Tags: http

Как организовать передачу на сервер файла с именем «%^##76 / // \ ^^ [ ] : .jpg»? 
Каждый символ там критически важен. Что будет на сервере, мы не знаем, и нас это совершенно не волнует.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. И добавьте правильные метки, пожалуйста.

Comment: В большинстве файловых систем косая черта используется для разделения пути и не допустима в именах файлов, так что совершенно не понятно, откуда у вас взялся такой файл. Что касается http то вы можете закодировать все недопустимые символы в виде `%xx` где xx шестнадцетиричный код символа

Answer (score 0):

По протоколу http можно передать "не корректные символы" в 16тиричном формате %xx, например, символ процента - это %25.
Сооттветственно, пример htttp GET запроса с символом % будет такой:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%25
```

Для всей строчки GET запрос будет такой:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%25%5E%23%2376+%2F+%2F%2F+%5E%5E%5B%5D%3A+.jpg
```

Что б отправить файл, нужно использовать POST запрос, гуглите, как это сделать, начните здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data. Идея та же - использовать 16ти ричную кодировку для не корректных символов.

**Справочная информация:**

1) Кодирование с помощью знака %: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data

2) Онлайн преобразование символов в формат Percent-encoding: https://www.urlencoder.org/